# Custom data collector for profile is visualy broken

Tags: symfony

I have created the custom data collector for profiler as described here http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/profiler/data_collector.html . 
Now everything is working correctly except of {% block panel %} in template  which defines the content area for my information. I have everything in place but on the screen tha page is almost without styles so its visualy broken.

When I compare my panel page and some other from profiler the mine lacks of cca. 200 lines of styles that Symfony is adding to the page header to style the page. I miss style for #content as an example. I tried to clear cache and refreshed everything but still now way. Any idea what is going to be wrong here?

This is waht I see in the browser ...
[image]

EDITED: Template

```
{% extends 'WebProfilerBundle:Profiler:layout.html.twig' %}

{% block toolbar %}

{% endblock %}

{% block head %}

{% endblock %}

{% block menu %}
    <span class="label">
        <strong>NET.Notes</strong>

    </span>
{% endblock %}

{% block panel %}

  panel david

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Could you show what your template looks like ?

Comment: I used the minimal version as you can see in in edited post above. I cant see any error, just style are missing.

Comment: You also get the error that the styles are missing ? Have you done assets install and assetic dump, if you use assetic ? Have you also added the template inside your config file?

Comment: No, all those styley are defined on page generated by Symfony. They are not linked. Profile page is iframe, if you view iframe source in your profiler you can see the list of styles at the top defined in <style></style> section. This is why its strange for me that some styles are missing ... at least 200 lines when I compare it with correct page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is due to empty block of "head". Rust remove it or include parent block by {{parent()}}.

```
{% block head %}
    {#if the web profiler panel needs some specific JS or CSS files #}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: GREAT! It really helpded !